# Completely Transparent Status Bar doesn't work on some devices

Tags: android, statusbar

Hi I am trying to develop a page with completely transparent status bar and white Navigation bar. I am using

`getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility( SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);`

In fragment.xml in parent layout I have used 
`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`
But it is not working on some devices. It is showing an overlay in status bar on some devices.Though, it is working fine on some devices. Please help me out this.
I have also tried setting Full screen flag but it causes my status bar font to disappear.
I have also used statusBarUtil library but it causes navigation bar to turn black.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to hide the ActionBar:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: It causes null pointer exception as I have disabled action bar in it. I am not using action bar in my whole application

Answer (score 0):

using immersive mode

```
   window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
```

more information check it out:
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive